# flickr and wordpress integration don't do it

Tags: wordpress, flickr

Here is the code that shows a photo from flickr

THIS USER : 53335537@N04 doesn't show ANYTHING - NADA

but this user : 85173533@N00 work great

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    var cesc = new flickrshow('flickrbox', {
       'autoplay':true,
       'hide_buttons':false,
       'interval':3500,
       'page':1,
       'per_page':10,
       'user':'53335537@N04'});
    });
    </script>
```

Question : Why a user doesn't work....

This address work great, so flickr is not blocking it
http://www.flickr.com/photos/53335537@N04

Here is the "live" page.... upper right : http://www.notrepanorama.com/1-la-table-et-ses-partenaires/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to call this URL: http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=6cb7449543a9595800bc0c365223a4e8&extras=url_s,url_m,url_z,url_l&format=json&jsoncallback=flickrshow_jsonp_22262679527&page=1&per_page=10&license=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&method=flickr.photos.search&user_id=53335537@N04&

which returns an empty result set:

```
flickrshow_jsonp_22262679527({"photos":{"page":1, "pages":0, "perpage":10, "total":"0", "photo":[]}, "stat":"ok"})
```

[Removing the `license=1,2,3,4,5,6,7` param causes results to be returned](http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=6cb7449543a9595800bc0c365223a4e8&extras=url_s,url_m,url_z,url_l&format=json&jsoncallback=flickrshow_jsonp_22262679527&page=1&per_page=10&method=flickr.photos.search&user_id=53335537@N04&)

So this user has apparently not licensed his images under one of the listed licenses.  Flickrshow has this to say about that parameter:

> A comma seperated list of the
>   allowable licenses within your
>   slideshow. If set to null, no license
>   restrictions will be set so please
>   ensure you have permission to display
>   the images. See the Flickr API for
>   more information on license codes.

Here's the relevant doc page from flickr: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html

It seems that embedding that user's images, since they're marked "all rights reserved", is legally questionable (although I'm guessing in this case, the embedder and the photo owner are the same person).  flickrshow only displays images with CC licenses by default, it seems.

So, in the end: either relicense the photos, or override flickrshow's license filter (probably by adding `'license':null,` to your params)

Comment: how do you capture the returning result ?

Comment: I just snagged the URL being requested in firebug, and opened it in a new tab.